# Cross-Browser jQuery text-zoom implementation

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, zooming, font-size

I've got some code to increase/decrease font size. This is giving me a headache because each browser seems to implement the `$.css('font-size')` differently ([see jquery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4296)). The part that's really killing me, though, is that Firefox is scaling up okay, but when I use the scale down function below, it *scales up*.  Webkit & IE are both working as expected. Any ideas on that?

I put this in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/srQ3P/1/ where you can see it working as expected, and you can see it broken in firefox at the project page: http://cumberlandme.info/residents

---

#### MAJOR EDIT

Sorry, the issue is not the code, it's firefox buggy behavior.  After I zoom in or out with the browser controls (ctrl + plus  or  ctrol + minus) the js goes haywire.  This doesn't happen in other browsers.  This is the real issue. Any advice on *that*

Comment: I'm curious, why implement your own thing? All the major browsers I know of have zooming, seems like this is a user-agent thing rather than your problem...

Comment: I totally agree.  I always thought it was stupid when a site offers the little plus-text, minus-text buttons.  But as I've "learned" from my client ;)   Many people don't know about that browser method, and so the site should offer the buttons.  So I could just leave it as it is, it works well enough.  But I hate to not have it "as perfect as possible", y'know?

Comment: i have firefox on macos it seams to work perfectly well. And people that have troubble with viewing, perfectly know that the browser has a zoom function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was with my javascript text zooming function.  The original function I used (found online) looked for a specific em value in the body font style and if it did not find one, reset the font size to '1em'.  Like so:

```
if (document.body.style.fontSize == "")
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1em";
document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.1) + "em";
```

This worked (why, I don't know) okay on IE, but not Ffx.  So the solution I came up with checks for IE and does things slightly differently based on if the browser is IE or not.  It's worth nothing that the jQuery docs recommend against checking for the browser in this way, but I did it anyway!

```
var currSz = parseFloat($('body').css('font-size'));
Math.round(currSz);

if($.browser.msie)
    currSz++;
else
    currSz = currSz + .7;

$('body').css('font-size',currSz);
```